# How to solve different Preview/Picture sizes returned by android.hardware.camera?

Tags: android, android-camera

So I've been playing with the android camera library and using it in a surfaceview. I have found that there's no way to capture pictures that match preview. In fact, one has to always check the preview and picture sizes and set the camera parameters to get the best match possible. Also, you can't just set the camera to have the same sizes for both since the app will crash if the camera doesn't support them.

How can this be? Is there really no other solution? I mean Instagram seems to use it (it doesn't launch the phone's camera app) and there always seems to be a perfect match.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simplest, and largely practical, approach is treat the preview as a mere feedback mechanism and to concentrate the program logic on getting the best - and desired - quality of image capture.

There is little novelty in mixing the two together.

Also, the desired image capture quality may depend on different factors/options. Based on post capture processing times, storage constraints, upload constraints, and more; the best quality image may not be the always desired one.

Implementation wise, the camera apps follow some common practices as below:

1. Use Camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes() to get the complete list.
2. Decide the best fit depending upon the constraints.
3. Some apps implement device specific best fit logic. Mostly, the popular devices get targeted.